# Laravel in cookies

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

The value is stored in cookies in each post but the condition does not work! Does anyone know what might be the problem?

```
public function like(Request $request){

        $id=$request->id;
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $cook_name = "user+$id";
        $cook_val = "$id";
        setcookie($cook_name,$cook_val, time() + (3600),"/show/$id");

        if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cook_name])) {

            $like_count = $post->like_count+1;
            $post->like_count = $like_count;
            $post->is_liked = 1;
            $post->save();
        }
```

Comment: If you are using Laravel already use helpers that it provides https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#cookies also what version of Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with following statement you are passing $id as a string:

```
setcookie($cook_name,$cook_val, time() + (3600),"/show/".$id);
```

Comment: did not help , Without specifying a page work on the whole site